# How to automatically set the value of a many to many field in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a blogPost model which has authors, reviewers and tags. The three fields are part of a ManyToMany relationship. But I want to set the value of each field in programmatic way.

Right now I can do this:

```py
blog.authors.set(qs)
```

This works, but this mean that I have to repeat the same line of code for each field.
I was thinking something like this

```py
def set_values(blog, field, new_values):
    setattr(blog, field, new_values)
```

that didn't work and it raises and exception telling me to use the `set` method.
But is there a way to implement something like this?

Comment: Given you would have to call `set_values` for each field, I don't see how that is going to be an improvement on `blog.authors.set(qs)` etc.

Comment: HI @cnk I just want to do something like this: 

```python 
for field,values in my_dict.items():

     set_values(blog, field,values)
```
I just want to improve a little bit my code and avoid repeating myself. 
`my_dict` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is:

```
def set_values(blog, field, new_values):
    getattr(blog, field).set(new_values)
```

but - unless this code snippet is massively simplified from your real-world code - I'd say it isn't worth the extra complexity over just repeating the line of code three times. Sometimes, simple, repetitive, readable code is better than "clever" code.